# Grab every TD then format it to currency

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm pretty new to JS and after searching through the web, docs, friends and another questions here on stackoverflow I've gotten until this point. Now I can't get pass it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $table = $("table.valores");

  if ($table.length > 0) {
    var ValorTh = $("th.header:contains('Valor')");
    var ValorColumnIndex = $(ValorTh).index();
    var Valor_rows = $($table).find('tr');

      $(Valor_rows).each(function() {
      $(this).find('td').eq(ValorColumnIndex).toLocaleString('pt-BR',{style:'currency', currency: 'BRL'});
    });

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="valores">
<thead><th class="header">Valor</th></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>15.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >16.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >17.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >18.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >19.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >20.00</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

I can't get the following to work and properly format the td's value :C

```
toLocaleString('pt-BR',{style:'currency',  currency: 'BRL'});
```

Comment: You can share our output and input because your ask isn't clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually set the content of the `td`s. Now, you don't change the content of the elements. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $table = $("table.valores");

  if ($table.length > 0) {
    var ValorTh = $("th.header:contains('Valor')");
    var ValorColumnIndex = $(ValorTh).index();
    var Valor_rows = $($table).find('tr');

      $(Valor_rows).each(function() {
        var $td = $(this).find('td').eq(ValorColumnIndex);
        var formatted = Number($td.text()).toLocaleString('pt-BR', {style:'currency', currency: 'BRL'});
        $td.text(formatted); // <-- here, you need to set the value
      });

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="valores">
<thead><th class="header">Valor</th></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>15.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >16.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >17.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >18.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >19.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >20.00</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!
I'm learning javascript now and it's pretty overwhelming... 
Before your answer i've got to this part:
var $td = $(this).find('td').eq(ValorColumnIndex);
But wasn't sure how to procede 
Was trying to do something like $td.textContent.toLocaleString and whatnot

Comment: Your understanding is correct. The last part `$td.text(formatted);` is jQuery equivalent of `.innerText = formatted` which basically changes the content of the `td` element as text

Comment: Humm... Now i understand it, thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

It's because `toLocaleString` is a prototype of `Number` and not `string`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $table = $("table.valores tbody");
  
  $table.find("td").each(function(i,el){
    try{
        $(el).text(parseFloat($(el).text()).toLocaleString('pt-BR', {style:'currency', currency: 'BRL'}));
        }catch(e){
          //not a number 
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="valores">
<thead><th class="header">Valor</th></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>15.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >16.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >17.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >18.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >19.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >20.00</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```